# Why Listview.getCheckedItemPositions returns empty in onItemLongClickListener?

Tags: android, android-listview

I use this to highlight current selected element of a listview:

```
list.setItemChecked(pos,list.getCheckedItemPositions().get(pos));
```

When I put that code into onItemClickListener it works, but when I put it into onItemLongClickListener it does not work, because list.getCheckedItemPositions() return an empty array.

In my xml I defined the listview:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="248dp"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:longClickable="true" >
</ListView>
```

and I used a custom drawable (selector) for the background of the item's layout, so when I click on an item normally, the background turns into "activated" status, but when I do a long click it does not work.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
            list.setItemChecked(pos,list.getCheckedItemPositions().get(pos));
    });

list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, final int pos, long id) {
            list.setItemChecked(pos,list.getCheckedItemPositions().get(pos));
});
```

Comment: Please provide fully code.

Comment: @boiledwater done, it is very simple but it returns different results.